# Understanding nested lambda function behaviour in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to learn pure functional programming. But this code is puzzling me particularly the second line. I do not understand how the value `2` is passed to the variable `x`. Can somebody explain this nested *`lambda`* behaviour?

```
>>> square_func = lambda x: x**2
>>> function_product = lambda F, m: lambda x: F(x)*m
>>> square_func(2)
4
>>> function_product(square_func, 3)(2)
12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner lambda creates a function when the outer lambda is called. The outer lambda returns this function. This function is then called with the argument `2`.

Comment: could you please throw some lights on how the values are bound to variables?

Answer (score 2):

A good place to start would be to apply `type` to your definitions and see if it clarifies things. Also, I can't help but remark that something like Haskell would be a nicer place to start if you are interested in functional programming, even if you do not plan on using the language. That being said, here is what you get:

```
In [13]: type(square_func)
Out[13]: function

In [14]: type(function_product)
Out[14]: function

In [15]: type(square_func(2))
Out[15]: int

In [16]: type(function_product(square_func, 3))
Out[16]: function

In [17]: type(function_product(square_func, 3)(2))
Out[17]: int
```

So the puzzling part is the return type of `function_product(square_func, 3)`, which is a function itself, one that is presumably intended to take a single number and return a single number. You could write it as:

```
f = function_product(square_func, 3)
f(2)
```

Comment: So, when `function_product` is called `square_func` is binded to `F` and `3` to `m`, which then returns a function which is binded to `function_product` which when called with `2`, `x` is assigned this and `square_func` is called, which returns `4` and this in turn is multiplied with `m` which is `4`. So it'll finally return `12`. Is my understanding/interpretation correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a rule (or convention), if you follow the style guide, **not** to use `lambda` in the context you have used. The reason for this is exactly what made you turn to the internet in confusion. The flags are:

1. You are giving an **anonymous** function a **name**
2. There are multiple `lambda`. For a language that does not have nested anonymous functions, this is a code smell. *There must be a better way*

How about writing this way and reaping the benefits:

```
def function_product(F, m):      # returns inner, a function
    def inner(x):                # takes x, and closes over F and m from 
        return F(x)*m            # outer scope, hence a closure
    return inner
```

See, everything is clear because it's more readable now. Avoid `lambda`, maybe  except for callbacks,like in `sorted()`. Normal functions are objects, just like `10` and `hello` are.

Always do `import this`. :)

Answer (score 1):

`function_product` asks for a function and a variable, you passed `square_func` and 3. Then, the inner function of `function_product` takes the result of the function you passed (`square_func`) and multiply it by the variable you passed, so:

```
square_func(2)*3 = 12
```

Answer (score 1):

`function_product(square_func, 3)` returns other lamba function which can be defined implicitly like this:

```
lambda x: square_func(x)*3
```

next by calling the other lamba function you pass 2 to the variable x