# How can I translate this Lambda expression into a Python 'def' function?

Tags: python, function, lambda

How can I translate the following lambda expression into normal Python functions? What mistakes did I make, and what are the best ways to approach them?

```py
love = lambda x: lambda y: lambda z: x + y * z

def love(x):
    def love(y):
        def love(z):
            return x + y * z
        return love
print(love(x))
print(love(y))
print(love(z))
```

Comment: Relates to [Understanding nested lambda function behaviour in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391807/understanding-nested-lambda-function-behaviour-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should return function for first two arguments.

```
def love(x):
    def f1(y):
        def f2(z):
            return x+y*z
        return f2
    return f1

print(love(2)(3)(4))  # return 2+3*4
# 14
```

Comment: Oh, I like this one!

Comment: here is the answer I'm looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
lamda x, y, z : x + y * z
```

therefore:

```
def func(x, y, z):
    return x + y * z
```

Comment: I would have thought so too!

Comment: Post is a nested lambda expression [Understanding nested lambda function behaviour in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36391807/understanding-nested-lambda-function-behaviour-in-python) so returns a function not a number.

Comment: Well, I thought he didn't know about lambda taking multiple inputs.